# Can I save a different AR object from the one I'm in via a callback in RoR3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, callback

I've got 2 tables in my DB. `users` and `trackers`.

Each `Tracker` has a `user_id` relating to the `users` table as you'd expect.

The context of this app is that it's part of a team based time tracking solution. As part of this I need to sort users by the total amount of time they've tracked to date and also display this total on screen.

So I figured that whenever a `Tracker` is saved I fire a `before_save` callback that grabs the `start_time` and `end_time` values from the `Tracker` object and does a simple `(end_time - start_time).to_i` to get the time of the tracker in seconds. The outcome is saved to `Tracker.tracked_time`. This part works and I can see the calculated value in the DB.

I now need to save a total result of all `Tracker` instances' `tracked_time` value per user and then I'd like to store this value to the `users` table in the `tracked_time` column there so that I can pull this out from the database to sort results by (think: most active user, least active user, top 10).

However when I try calling this `before_save :calculate_tracked_time, if: :finished?, unless: :admin?` I simply get a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved` error.

It appears that I cannot save a value on a `User` model while inside the `Tracker` module… but I have no clue as to why or how else to do what I need.

Any thoughts on how to make this work (or work better perhaps) would be much appreciated.

Oh and the `:tracked_time` on the `User` model is listed in the `attr_accessible` so it can be written to.

Below is the `Tracker` model, I can also post the `User` model if needed.

```
class Tracker < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :running, :start_time, :end_time, :tracked_time, :intention, :achievement
  belongs_to :user

  before_save :calculate_tracked_time, if: :finished?, unless: :admin?

  validates :user_id,   presence: true
  validates :intention, presence: true,
                        length: { minimum: 5 }

  default_scope order: 'trackers.created_at DESC'

  private

    def finished?
      # Only save the total amount of time elapsed if we have
      # a start_time AND end_time for this object.
      !self.end_time.nil?
    end

    def admin?
      # Don't calculate totals for the admin user.
      User.find_by_id( self.user_id ).admin?
    end

    def calculate_tracked_time

      # write the tracker's tracked time value in seconds
      self.tracked_time = ( self.end_time - self.start_time ).to_i

      # update the user's tracked time total
      user = User.find_by_id( self.user_id )
      # calculate time from all trackers this user has
      total_time = 0
      user.trackers.each { |t| total_time += t.tracked_time }
      # this log correctly prints the correct figures.
      p "Total Time for user (#{self.user_id}): #{total_time}"
      # store it to the user's :tracked_time db column
      user.tracked_time = total_time
      # save !!! Errors out.
      user.save
    end

end
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Have you tried using user.update_column(:tracked_time, total_time) instead of updating and calling save? update_column doesn't call any callbacks, which may be giving you an issue.

Comment: Wow, that did it! It's now working as expected. Thank you. Want to post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of updating the field and calling save, try using update_column:

```
user.update_column(:tracked_time, total_time)
```

update_column doesn't call any callbacks (or validations, so you do need to be careful). Callbacks can prevent saving when you're already in a callback.